# Why scrapy-proxies shows my IP instead of proxy?

Tags: python, proxy, scrapy, web-crawler

I am using scrapy and to prevent IP ban I want to use scrapy-proxies. [this one](https://github.com/aivarsk/scrapy-proxies) As it is stated in documents I am doing the configuration like this in my settings.py.

```py
RETRY_TIMES = 10
RETRY_HTTP_CODES = [500, 503, 504, 400, 403, 404, 408]

DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware': 90,
    'scrapy_proxies.RandomProxy': 100,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 110,
}

PROXY_LIST = 'path/ips.txt'
PROXY_MODE = 0
```

Then in my spider:

```py
class Test(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "test"
    start_urls = ['http://checkip.dyndns.org/']

    def parse(self, response):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            request = scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.check_ip)
            yield request

    def check_ip(self, response):
        pub_ip = response.xpath('//body/text()').re('\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}')[0]
        print ("My public IP is: " + pub_ip)

process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(Urunler)
process.start()
```

However I am getting my own IP Address. Am I missing something here ?

Comment: Where did you get your proxy lists from? Sometimes proxies are transparent proxies, which means they do forward your IP to the server, in which case it will still show your ip. You should test your proxy online for the same

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I got where I was doing wrong. I don't know why but my spider isn't getting the settings from settings.py. That is why proxy thing wasn't working